# Smallest Two's Complement in Binary

Tags: binary

I'm not sure if I can ask a binary question here but here goes.. 
We had this question on our midterm but our professor hasn't provided a correct answer for it. It's been driving me crazy and the final is coming soon so it might be a good idea to fill this gap. Thanks!

Find the smallest two's complement number that, when added to `0101 0101` would result in an overflow. Express your answer in binary.

My reasoning: 
I found the range of the original binary `0101 0101` by converting it to an actual number and then added one to it. Then I converted the number that was 1 more than the range into 8-bit binary as my answer. However, this only earned me 3/6 marks. I have no idea what else I could've done. Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The original binary is a positive number (0 sign bit). Overflow occurs when you add a positive number to it that changes the sign bit. It should be easy to see what the smallest number is using binary notation:

**No overflow:**

```
  0101 0101
+ 0010 1010
  ---------
  0111 1111
```

**Overflow:**

```
  0101 0101
+ 0010 1011
  ---------
  1000 0000
```

I have no idea if this is what your prof was looking for. (You can probably just subtract from `1000 0000` instead of looking at it as a pattern.)

**EDIT** Since you asked for an example (meaning something different from the above), here's how subtraction would work:

```
  1000 0000 (the target overflow quantity)
- 0101 0101 (the original binary)
  ---------
  0010 1011 (the smallest number that will overflow when added to original)
```

Comment: +1 for the subtraction. Basically, figure out the first number that would overflow (`1000 000`) and then figure out how far away you are from that number (ie, subtract from it).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was helpful! =3 Could I see an example though? ^^

Answer (score 0):

That number is 85 in decimal, so 128-85 is 43